# Is there ultra HD support in Linux?

Tags: linux, display, compatibility, high-definition

I wonder what the current state of this is? Any distro that supports very high ppi as of today? I have read that mageia offers support, but I wonder if that is truly the case? i find it strange specially because the most relevant DEs apparently don't work well yet?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the distro, if mageia can do it, then so can everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

As Linux uses X11 to do graphical rendering, this question is really about whether X11 supports it.

The answer is yes, X11 supports arbitrary sizes. One example with 4K HD is [here](http://dissociatedpress.net/the-4k-desktop-on-fedora/).

Comment: Thanks!  I don't understand, though... How is it possible that such massive resolution apparently does not imply more pixels and a higher pixel density? I can clearly see pixels in that image...

Comment: Resolution in the computer world correlates directly to pixel count. PPI/DPI/pixel density exists only in the real world.

Consider 1080p TVs for example... a 19" 1080p TV has a much higher pixel density than a 60" 1080p TV, but the resolution (and signal on the wire) is still identical.

Comment: Exactly, that's why, given the fact computer monitors are not that big, pixel density should be amazing in that picture... Probably around 300 ppi for a twenty inches monitor. So yeah, confused that it's not like that at all in that screen.

Comment: The image is 3840x2160 - if you "see pixels" you're looking at your own display. The pixel density is only dependent on the physical hardware (on my 27" 2560x1440 screen, I can't see them at a normal viewing distance).